# Is there a "Keep-going" flag for configure scripts?

Tags: build, compilation, makefile, dependencies, configure

There's a flag for the `make` program that causes the compilation to go as far as possible to show as many errors as possible.

From `make(1)`:

```
   -k, --keep-going
        Continue  as  much  as  possible after an error.  While the target
        that failed, and those that depend on it, cannot  be  remade,  the
        other dependencies of these targets can be processed all the same.
```

I was wondering if there's anything one can do to get the same behavior from `./configure` scripts.

I was trying to `./configure` [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im) to install it from source. But the configure script kept bugging me about dependencies that I don't need, and my only solution to the interruptions was to give `--disable` flags to the configure script.

That's why I would like to run through the configure script as far as possible so that it can notify me of *all* the dependencies at once. That way I can choose which I need to `--disable` and which I need to install, in one pass rather than having to run the configure script for each and every unmet dependency.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`autoconf` doesn't have a concept of dependencies, so the person building the `autoconf` input would have to do that for themselves and it would be highly painful.  And the reason `autoconf` doesn't try is that, while compilation dependencies in a `Makefile` are generally simple, figuring build dependencies can be complex — and even when they're simple, it needs to be done in `m4` so it's going to be nightmarish.  (`m4` is easy for computers but hard for people.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's not possible. If the author of `configure.ac` decides to use `exit` from the script there's not much we can do about it. Normal way (using **AC_MSG_ERROR** et al.) calls `exit` too (Here have a look at `as_fn_exit` function.)
You may try though to hack the configure script and change calls to `exit` to something that doesn't quit. But beware that the logic may be broken completely…